# delete file with rest services

Tags: services

> services version 7.x-3.1   drupal version 7.12

I upload file in Base64 encoding with rest services

> resource_path: file.json

how can i delete file with rest services?
i now how to delete node

> resource_path:node/nid.json,  resource_type:DELETE

i test

> resource_path:file/fid.json,  resource_type:DELETE

but receive 404!

Comment: Sorry to ask this question  
i did it With the same method ('resource_path:file/fid.json' with 'DELETE resource_type')  
error404 happened for another mistake